# Which approach is better for processing missing data in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

I have some table and trying to get the primary key when record exists for specified filters otherwise I need my function to return NULL value.

I can do it either this way

```
function getIdIfExists(pParam number) return number is
  resultId number;
begin
  begin
    select ID into resultId from mytable where some_condition = pParam and rownum = 1;
    exception when NO_DATA_FOUND then
       resultId := NULL;
  end;

  return resultId;
end;
```

or this way:

```
function getIdIfExists(pParam number) return number is
  resultId number := NULL;
begin
  for item in (select * into resultId from mytable where some_condition = pParam) loop
    resultId := item.ID;
    exit;
  end loop;
  return resultId;
end;
```

So which one is better? Or may be there is a different approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one (using SQL rather than a loop) is significantly better as you are utilising the SQL engine to search the data rather than manually checking every single row in the table using PL/SQL. The cardinal rule when using PL/SQL is if you can do it in SQL, don't do it in PL/SQL.

However, your first example will need modifying to use an aggregate function such as MAX to ensure that only one row is ever returned otherwise multiple rows will throw an exception.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
FUNCTION getIdIfExists(p_id NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER
IS
   resultId NUMBER;
BEGIN
   SELECT   MAX(id)
   INTO     resultId
   FROM     mytable
   WHERE    some_condition = p_id;

   RETURN resultId;
END;
```

Edit: I actually misread the second example and didn't see that you had a `WHERE` clause in there. Given that, the second example is actually bugged as it has no ORDER BY so given multiple matches the SQL engine could return different results for the same input over multiple executions. The first example (modified to use an aggregate function) is still a cleaner way to achieve what you want though.

Comment: I would say using exception handling is fine, after all no rows is what you'd class as an exceptional event given that a specific ID has been provided to the function, inferring that it is expected to exist.

Comment: I don't understand why you would ever need the NO_DATA_FOUND ??? MAX(...) Always returns a value, If no data in the select matches your query the aggregate will be NULL. The exception block is wrong and will only irritate developers

Comment: Whoops, right you are. That was a leftover from the example in the question that I used as a base for my answer. I've edited it now.

Answer (score 1):

Your first example will raise a TOO_MANY_ROWS exception if more than one row matches the condition. The second example will iterate through all the rows which match the condition and return the ID of the last one. Your choice as to which behavior you prefer.

Share and enjoy.

Comment: Ok, I edited my examples a bit, so such situations should not happen

Comment: Your edited example actually introduces a bug - using rownum is a very bad idea as you're basically saying "give me a row from the results, I don't care which one" since you have no ORDER BY.

Answer (score 1):

So if your question is, which style of SQL is faster than have a look at the following experiment:
This code snipped loops 10000 x  "select dummy from dual" in three different ways:

1. explicit cursor
2. implicit cursor
3. select ... into ... (which in fact is also an implicit cursor)

Here is the Code:

```
procedure cursor_style_compare is
    l_start_time number;
    l_duration   number;
    l_dummy      dual.dummy%type;

    cursor c_explicit is
        select dummy from dual;
 begin
    -- Explicit Cursors:
    l_start_time := dbms_utility.get_time;
    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
        for c1 in c_explicit loop
            null;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    l_duration := dbms_utility.get_time - l_start_time;
    dbms_output.put_line('Explicit Cursor:     ' || to_char(l_duration));

    -- Implicit Cursors (1):
    l_start_time := dbms_utility.get_time;
    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
        for c1 in (select dummy from dual) loop
            null;
        end loop;
    end loop;
    l_duration := dbms_utility.get_time - l_start_time;
    dbms_output.put_line('Implicit Cursor (1): ' || to_char(l_duration));

    -- Implicit Cursors (2):
    l_start_time := dbms_utility.get_time;
    for i in 1 .. 10000 loop
        select dummy into l_dummy from dual;
    end loop;
    l_duration := dbms_utility.get_time - l_start_time;
    dbms_output.put_line('Implicit Cursor (2): ' || to_char(l_duration));

end;
```

If I run this code on my local database (Oracle 11.2 SE on Windows Server), the Result is:

```
Explicit Cursor:     43
Implicit Cursor (1): 41
Implicit Cursor (2): 31
```

So the simple "select ... into ..." is the fastest way to get data if the result is just a single row. This is also the official recommendation of Oracle: 
[Working with Cursors (by Steven Feuerstein)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-mar/o23plsql-1906474.html)